# How do I remove the outermost wrappers using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

Example xml is:

```
<a amp="a"><b><c>this is the text</c></b></a>
```

Needs to be transformed to:

```
<a amp="a"><c>this is the text</c></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution #1:** A slight improvement to **smaccoun**'s solution that would preserve any attributes on the `c` element (not necessary for example XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="c">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Solution #2** Another alternative that leverages the **[built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule)**, which apply-templates for all elements and copy all `text()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <!--identity template for the c element, it's decendant nodes, 
        and attributes (which will only get applied from c or 
        descendant elements)-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|c//node()|c">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Solution #3:** A modified **[identity transform:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <!--identity template, copies all content by default-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--don't generate content for these matched elements, 
        just apply-templates to it's children-->
    <xsl:template match="a|b">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Solution #4** If you know what you want, just copy it from a match on the root node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="a/b/c" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you want to simply remove the `<b>` element from your input, then a modified identity transform should be used with a template matching the `<b>` element that simply applies templates to it's children.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <!--identity template, copies all content by default-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--don't generate content for the <b>, just apply-templates to it's children-->
    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1. Also, identity transform pattern is the name I was thinking of, not 'copy design pattern'. Didn't know that it would copy the attributes as text, good to know!

Comment: Mads, can you look at the edit i made. I wanted a to be preserved but b to be removed

Comment: You would want to use Solution #3, just remove `a` from the match criteria, so that it is handled by the generic match on `@*|node()`, which will copy the content. The match on `b` will suppress it's content, but apply templates to it's children, which will also match the generic template that copies to the output.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the template on `<c>` and then just use a copy design pattern.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match='c'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works for this instance document. However, if `<c>` had attributes, the values would be copied as text content, rather than being preserved. (e.g. `<c amp="foo">this is the text</c>` would result in `<c>foothis is the text</c>`)